# EDITED:Command \item working differently than before in environment [CV] (using package CV) in MikTex 2.9

Tags: cv

Have used LaTex and package CV for the last 5+ years to write my CV. Using the same code that has worked many times before on a new install (MikTex 2.9) I receive error messages for each time I use \item. The Minimum Working Example looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CV}
\begin{document}
\section{Professional Experience}
\begin{CV}
\item [01/2000-12/2000] \textbf{Title1}, Employer1, Location1
\item [01/1999-12/1999] \textbf{Title2}, Employer2, Location2
\end{CV}
\end{document}
```

The error messages are "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)" and "Missing number, treated as zero".

Grateful for any advice on why this is happening and how to resolve it. Thanks!

[Edited based on reponses by BambOo & Mensch. The first line of the log file reads: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit) (preloaded format=latex 2019.9.6)  17 SEP 2019 10:54]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Please delete all personal informations, use dummy text instead ... And please add the first line of your log file to your question, then we can see your used tex distribution and version number

Comment: Thank you @Mensch and BambOo, I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: the MWE compiles without problems using the current texlive distribution

Comment: Do the date ranges 01/2000-12/2000 show up in your pdf @ebcontrol ? I just de-installed MikTex and installed the current texlive distribution, but still have the same problem...

Comment: yes, I get both date ranges correctly

Comment: Well, then I guessyou are loading an outdated package on your system. That can be a local one in the same directory your tex code is or an local variant in an included localtexfm. That can only be checked by seening the complete log file for your given code ...